# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'createFromFormat' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in

Tags: php, mysql

This is about room reservation site. I need to save the reservation dates in few rows by increase one day until the days i want to reserve. I'm new to php so i'm very thanksful to anyone who can simply explain me the problm. Here is the code.

```
$today=date("Y/m/d");
$date = new DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $in);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("royal", $con);
{echo $i."<br>";
for ($y=1; $norooms>=$y; $y++)
    {
    echo "Day difference=".$len." No of rooms=".$norooms."<br>";
    $date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
    $sql="INSERT INTO singlerooms (Date,Ref_Date)VALUES ($date,$today)";
    mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? The createFromFormat() method was introduced in PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 9):

You don't need the `new` keyword there. `createFromFormat()` is a [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) in the `DateTime` class.  It should be called as follows:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $in);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `php5.3` then you should have this function available.

Code snippet. Remove `new` keyword.

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Your code: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $in);`

Docs Link: http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date1 = $date->createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $in);
```